# How to install a particular version of opencv from homebrew?

Tags: opencv, homebrew

How to install a particular version of OpenCV from homebrew?

I wanna install OpenCV 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brew install opencv@3` would be what you are looking for. The formula source code is in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv@3.rb).

Comment: I recently installed opencv3 for python 3.7 using brew install opencv@3, but the cv2.imread function doesn't work at all (no built in function, apparently)

What is the problem?

Comment: From the source code I see, it is actually built with python 3.8 though.